# In Hearts, played by experts, what is ratio of shooting the moon?

Tags: statistics, hearts

Because nobody knows the game-theoretical-optimal strategy in Hearts, I am looking for an approximation based on empirical data. For example, based on logs of games between expert players from an online server, or from records of championship events.

I'm particularly curious about the J♦︎ variant, and the difference in the shoting the moon ratio w/o the J♦︎ variant.  In that variant, the J♦︎ is worth -10 points.

NOTE:  This is *not* a duplicate of this [question](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/11336/what-are-the-chances-of-shooting-the-moon-in-hearts).  That question doesn't qualify in what context the game is being played.  This question does, and as such, it will have an objective answer, but only if someone has access to a decent data set of games.

Comment: Do you have to take the jack of diamonds to shoot the moon?

Comment: @JoeW No, 'shooting the moon' involves getting all of the hearts and the queen of spades (all the cards that would normally give you points), and instead of you getting the points everyone else does.

Comment: The results of shooting the moon depend on what rules you are playing by. In some rules you get the option of either everyone else getting 26 points or taking 26 points off your score. Which is why I asked the question about the jack of diamonds since you made no indication on if that was needed to shoot the moon or not.

Comment: Funny how in English the game is called Hearts whereas in French it is called Queen of Spades (Dame de pique).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the chances of shooting the moon in Hearts?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/11336/what-are-the-chances-of-shooting-the-moon-in-hearts)

Comment: This is not quite a duplicate of that question - that one asks what the probability is from a theoretical standpoint, and this from an empirical one.

Comment: I'd say the "by experts" bit put this empirical query on the same footing as the theory.

Comment: @L.ScottJohnson sure, the shooting rate for the Nash Equilibrium strategy is a theoretical alternative on same footing. The linked-to question though doesn’t ask that, and so is of little interest or relevance.

Comment: Try to ask Einar Egilsson from https://cardgames.io/  , he is very responsive and probably has the data.  Email:  admin@cardgames.io.

Comment: I got in touch with Einar. He says their site only allows playing against computer opponents. So his data is not useful for this question.

Comment: I think his data is interesting in two ways: what % of rounds will result in *human* shooting the moon? and what % of rounds will result in *his bots* shooting the moon?

Comment: He told me his bots are simple and never try to shoot the moon. If they do so it is always by accident. Also he says that the bots are not good at detecting and stopping others from shooting the moon.

Comment: @dshin, your title and your question are slightly out of sync.  Forget answered your title, but not your question.

Comment: Any suggestions on how to edit the title to get them in sync?

Answer (score -1):

Hearts involves the concept of (A) deciding exactly 3 cards (at least in the common 4 player variant) to change between each hand in 3/4 of the hands and (B) to keep all cards in 1/4 of them. 
A major enough distinction that I think they probably need to considered in these 2 different groups. Lets consider what hand distributions capable of taking all cards would look like and consider group B as more important as it is easier to site and is based off of which players will decide which cards to pass from their hands anyway.

There are a total of 39 distinct hand suit patterns, there is a large scale experiment of computer shuffled hands and results here
http://playbridge.com/pb_shuffle_project.php

These are suit independent so multiplication to increase these percentages is not needed, but certain constraints need to be taken into consideration and will reduce the percentages a significant amount. 
Basically to get the total you would need to add up the favorable results you get from each of the 39 hand patterns to get the total % of being able to shoot the moon.

### Below this point might be considered a tedious explanation on how these numbers are derived and in excess of what the question asked for, but in case of more curious readers, I thought I would include the general process as it can be used of any of the 39 hand patterns :) Edit: section added after to account for hand passing as requested.

Lets illustrate with having 2 sample hand patterns for a key in what to look for, will do 5-4-3-1 and 7-3-3-0 as examples.

1. 5-4-3-1, about 12.93% likely to get without caring which cards are in the suits. There are 24 possible arrangements between the suits in this chosen hand pattern,  lets add what restrictions we need 1 suit at a time.

For the 1 card suit we have 13 combinations of those, in 6 of the 24 suit arrangements this suit is clubs and does not need any restriction as a point card cannot be played on the first trick, for the other arrangements having the ace is safest and so would need to divide by 13.
For the 3 card suit we have 13 choose 3 combinations of those (or 286) and only 1 of them realiably has us winning all tricks (akq) and so would need to divide by 286 for all other arrangements.
For the 4 card suit we have 13 choose 4 combinations (or 715) and akqj would need needed a high percentage of the time so will need to divide by 715
For the 5 card suit we can finally have a little leeway; 13 choose 5 combinations (or 1287) and the suit could reliably run with just akqj, having those 4 cards accounted for 
we have 9 choose 1 combinations left so basically divide by 1287 and multiply by 9.

This leaves the result looking visually like this:
5-4-3-1: 12.93% 
A. 3.233% of which has 1 club.
B.  9.967% other arrangements

A. 3.233%/286/715/1287*9 or    1.11e-7 % or 11.1e-8 %

B. 9.967%/13/286/715/1287*9 or 2.55e-8 %

for a total of 1.365e-7 %

2. 7-3-3-0, about 0.2652% likely without caring about which suit or which cards. There are only 12 possible suit arrangements 6 of which have three clubs for instance, again going 1 suit at a time.

For the suit with no cards in it, no restrictions as nothing can be done about it anyway

For the suits with 3 cards 13 choose 3 (287) if one of them is clubs, (edit: this also holds true if the hand has no clubs at all) that suit can have ak and any of the 11 cards, the second 3 card suit for safety should probably be akq; thus the need to divide by 287 twice.

For the 7 card suit, we have 13 choose 7 (1716) combinations, since the suit is substantially longer, we probably only need akq for a relaible run most of the time, akqj for a nearly everytime running leaving 10 choose 4 (210) or 9 choose 3 (84) open slots.

So In total

0.2652% /287/287/1716*210 or 3.94e-7 %

---

Hand passing section:

For the cases where 3 cards are being passed, people try to shorten their already short suits and lengthen their strong ones. It can be helpful to pair 
your hand with that of the person passing to you, combining their suit lengths with yours, below is a table of the 44 fit classes breifly mentioned in the comment, the first 10 are by far the most common and in cases of passing across cannot be changed by the passing, placing a logical upper bound on how uneven the suits can be distributed.

(from Thomas Andrews Deal 3.1 documentation)
There are 103 fit patterns, or 65 if we consider our fit pattern and opponent's as the same (e.g., that 8-6-6-6 is the same as 7-7-7-5. If the sum of the longest fit and the shortest fit is 13, then the pattern is self-dual, for example, if our fit pattern is 9-7-6-4, then so is the opponent's.)

## Normalized |  Squares sum | Patterns

```
     0 |          170 | 7-7-6-6
     1 |          172 | 8-6-6-6,7-7-7-5
     2 |          174 | 8-7-6-5
     4 |          178 | 9-6-6-5,8-8-5-5,8-7-7-4
     5 |          180 | 9-7-5-5,8-8-6-4
     6 |          182 | 9-7-6-4
     8 |          186 | 10-6-5-5,9-8-5-4,8-8-7-3
     9 |          188 | 10-6-6-4,9-7-7-3
    10 |          190 | 10-7-5-4,9-8-6-3
    12 |          194 | 10-7-6-3,9-9-4-4
    13 |          196 | 11-5-5-5,10-8-4-4,9-9-5-3,8-8-8-2
    14 |          198 | 11-6-5-4,10-8-5-3,9-8-7-2
    16 |          202 | 11-7-4-4,11-6-6-3,10-7-7-2,9-9-6-2
    17 |          204 | 11-7-5-3,10-8-6-2
    18 |          206 | 10-9-4-3
    20 |          210 | 12-5-5-4,11-8-4-3,11-7-6-2,10-9-5-2,9-8-8-1
    21 |          212 | 12-6-4-4,9-9-7-1
    22 |          214 | 12-6-5-3,11-8-5-2,10-8-7-1
    24 |          218 | 12-7-4-3,10-10-3-3,10-9-6-1
    25 |          220 | 12-6-6-2,11-9-3-3,11-7-7-1,10-10-4-2
    26 |          222 | 12-7-5-2,11-9-4-2,11-8-6-1
    28 |          226 | 13-5-4-4,12-8-3-3,10-10-5-1,9-9-8-0
    29 |          228 | 13-5-5-3,12-8-4-2,11-9-5-1,10-8-8-0
    30 |          230 | 13-6-4-3,12-7-6-1,10-9-7-0
    32 |          234 | 13-6-5-2,12-8-5-1,11-10-3-2,11-8-7-0
    33 |          236 | 13-7-3-3,10-10-6-0
    34 |          238 | 13-7-4-2,12-9-3-2,11-10-4-1,11-9-6-0
    36 |          242 | 13-6-6-1,12-9-4-1,12-7-7-0
    37 |          244 | 13-7-5-1,12-8-6-0
    38 |          246 | 13-8-3-2,11-10-5-0
    40 |          250 | 13-8-4-1,12-9-5-0,11-11-2-2
    41 |          252 | 12-10-2-2,11-11-3-1
    42 |          254 | 13-7-6-0,12-10-3-1
    44 |          258 | 13-9-2-2,13-8-5-0,11-11-4-0
    45 |          260 | 13-9-3-1,12-10-4-0
    48 |          266 | 13-9-4-0
    50 |          270 | 12-11-2-1
    52 |          274 | 13-10-2-1,12-11-3-0
    54 |          278 | 13-10-3-0
    60 |          290 | 12-12-1-1
    61 |          292 | 13-11-1-1,12-12-2-0
    62 |          294 | 13-11-2-0
    72 |          314 | 13-12-1-0
    84 |          338 | 13-13-0-0
```

Comment: While this is a good lower mathematical bound, there are several major flaws with this answer. First, this is only an analysis of keep hands, which are only a quarter of hands and are typically the hardest to shoot on. Second, this assumes you must win all the tricks beyond the first to shoot the moon, which is not the case; you only need win all the tricks on which points are played. Finally, it assumes you need to have the 4 highest cards in each suit, which is also not true; other people may get rid of high cards on other tricks or be holding just the king which they must play to your ace.

Comment: Also, it is important to keep in mind that that there is a difference between being mathematically guaranteed to shoot the moon and actually shooting the moon.  When shooting the moon, you frequently get several tricks of leeway where everyone is avoiding taking points because they don't know you are trying to shoot yet.  And, if you hold the queen of spades in your hand until the last trick, people may not try to take the lead from you as they still risk 13 points for spoiling your moon shoot (this depends a lot on the current scores of the players).

Comment: Yes, it's only an analysis of keep hands, even hands where you eventually pass 3 cards to another player first start out being dealt according to the table. One would then have to look at about which cards are statistically chosen by each player to be passed given the hand that was actually originally dealt to them, direction of passing being dependent in some cases. Using qualities such was favoring short suits  high cards, clubs or not favoring low spades. Certainly you can add some more free cards or use second highest, etc. The original question asked for empirical data and is a good start

Comment: It might also be insightful that in the passing form of the game you can pair up your hand with the hand passing cards to you, combined they make up a fit pattern, there are 103 possible fit patterns divided into 44 different classes based on standard deviation, they are symmetric so that if you two have one fit class, the other 2 players have the exact same fit class. Example: you have 4 spades 2 hearts, 3 diamonds 4 clubs, the player on your left dealt 4 spades, 4 hearts, 3 diamonds 2 clubs with passing to right. together you two have 8 spades 6 hearts 6 Diamonds 6 Clubs or 8-6-6-6.

Comment: The opponents fit pattern would then be 7-7-7-5, which is in the same fit class as you. This is also the most likely of the 44 fit classes to be dealt out and passing strategies often use these to advantage.

Comment: It would help if you could put the actual answer at the top of your answer instead of having to pick it out of a wall of text. Also it should be a general answer for any hand type and not one for a hold and another for a pass hand.

Comment: Question flagged for bounty violation

Comment: By the rules of the site, the winner of a bounty is supposed to get a minimum of 1/2 of the reputation gain

Comment: which would be 25 or 50 in this case

Comment: The [bounty help page](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/help/bounty) states that a bounty will only be automatically awarded to answers with a score of 2 or greater. No answer on this question, including yours, has a high enough score, so no bounty was awarded.

Answer (score -2):

Undefined.

You have made the question a contradiction: There are no "*perfectly playing agents*", and thus there can be no empirical data on their results.

Reason: Hearts, like Contract Bridge, is [a stochastic game of incomplete information](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_bridge#Cardplay_algorithms): There is incomplete data throughout most of the play of each hand, meaning statistical likelihoods need to be estimated by each player for several rounds. There is no theoretic framework for such, and no evidence that even AI can do so in a foreseeable future.

Even in Contract Bridge, where additional information about the hidden hands is available from the bidding and one hand is face down on the table, there is o such thing as a perfectly playing agent, even considering just the play of the cards. The closest that is available is termed [*Double Dummy Analysis*](http://www.northerncoloradobridge.com/archives/playerscorner/Double_Dummy_Analysis.pdf), which presents an assessment of makeable contracts when ***both opponent hands are assumed visible for the play***.

So, until such time as a *perfectly playing agent* has at least been constructed for Contract Bridge, a game with one hand on the table for all players to see, there can be no such thing in the much more challenging conditions of a Hearts game, with all opponents always hidden.

---

**Addendum**

In card games such as Hearts and Contract Bridge, one of the most powerful analysis techniques is that of:

- drawing correct inferences from what other players *have not done*;
- then from an assessment of their habits and presumed skill making an assessment of holdings they **don't have**; and
- from this finally creating an assessment of what they might have by removing the eliminated possibilities.

This is an extremely challenging skill to master, even in Contract Bridge where at least one partnership, and often both, have participated in the auction and described their hands in considerable detail to both partnerships - as there are no secret bidding or play agreements in Bridge.

If this cannot even be approached perfectly in Bridge, imagine how much harder it will be in Hearts, where only the three cards you received on the Pass is available information about the other hands when the play starts.

Comment: John Nash proved the existence of a perfect strategy in hearts in 1950. You can read the proof here: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nash_equilibrium

Comment: Also, in 2019, being a stochastic game of imperfect information is no longer a reason the assume a game is intractable for AI. Poker shares these same characteristics and much progress has been made recently in that area leading to superhuman agents.

Comment: Also, I did not ask for empirical data between games played by perfect agents. Of course no such data can exist, as such agents do not exist, and probably never will. I’m asking for an educated guess based on the assumption that current world class players might shoot the moon at similar frequencies as perfect agents (which again are known to be theoretically possible due to John Nash’s 1950 proof).

Comment: @dshin Poker is not a game of imperfect knowledge as in the classic game of Texas Hold Em not only do you have knowledge of what can be in a players hands from the 5 cards on the tables but you can gain knowledge based on how the player bets over time.

Comment: @JoeW Imperfect information is a rigorously defined mathematically concept. Poker is an imperfect information game according to this definition.

Comment: @dshin Also it should be noted that the Nash equilibrium deals a lot with simultaneous decisions and in the game of hearts each player makes a decision based on the previous players play which when considering the possibility of shooting the moon players will be looking to stop it. Which in my mind means the probability of shooting the moon comes down to more luck of the draw then strategy itself

Comment: @dshin but you have a a massive amount of information in poker compared to hearts.

Comment: Nash equilibrium deals with simultaneous strategy choices. In settings like Hearts or poker, a strategy is defined as a mapping of all possible information states (which includes the history of all previous plays - this is greater than the number of atoms in the universe for Hearts) to probability distributions over actions. In this light, asking for the shooting the moon probability is a completely well defined mathematical question, with an exact numerical answer. It is as well-defined a question, mathematically, as asking for the value of 2+2.

Comment: You have information in Hearts as well. If I lead with the 2c and you then play the Ad, I now have a massive amount of information about your remaining 12 cards. Namely, that none of those 12 cards are clubs. This is similar to your poker example.

Comment: But that is one case where a player happens to be short suited which is not something that can be counted on to happen often

Comment: We started this discussion talking about the notion of imperfect information. In poker, there are situations where one player possesses knowledge about the game state that another does not. By definition then poker is an imperfect information game. Same for hearts. The question of whether poker or hearts involves more inference is an interesting one but not relevant to the question at hand.

Comment: @JoeW, An example for information gained in hearts: if a player passes you 3 low-medium diamonds, you can deduce that she might be void in diamonds.  

If some one play the 10s then the Js, you can deduce he does not holds the Qs.

Comment: @Cohensius I would strongly disagree with you on the second point. I have seen it happen plenty of times when a person is deep in Spades and has the Queen of spades they will act like they are fishing for for it in order to throw others off.

Comment: nice!  I am not a hearts expert, my point is that you can infer about other players hands by their moves.